# PLS-00357: Table,View Or Sequence reference not allowed in this context

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I want to write an update procedure in my package body. It works fine before I added this IF statement. I want to check that only if the new value is different from the old value, I update it. Otherwise, I don't update it. Then I got this error: `Error(39,22): PLS-00357: Table,View Or Sequence reference 'USER.TABLE_NAME.FIRSTNAME' not allowed in this context`. Below is my procedure code:

```
PROCEDURE updateTABLE (
  v_code        IN      USER.TABLE_NAME.CODE%TYPE,
  v_id          IN      USER.TABLE_NAME.ID%TYPE,
  v_firstname   IN      USER.TABLE_NAME.FIRSTNAME%TYPE,
  v_lastname    IN      USER.TABLE_NAME.LASTNAME%TYPE,
  v_email       IN      USER.TABLE_NAME.EMAIL%TYPE,
  v_phone       IN      USER.TABLE_NAME.PHONE%TYPE
) IS
BEGIN
IF USER.TABLE_NAME.FIRSTNAME != v_firstname OR
   USER.TABLE_NAME.LASTNAME != v_lastname OR
   USER.TABLE_NAME.EMAIL != v_email OR
   USER.TABLE_NAME.PHONE != v_phone THEN
UPDATE USER.TABLE_NAME
        SET FIRSTNAME = v_firstname,
            LASTNAME = v_lastname,
            EMAIL = v_email,
            PHONE = v_phone,
            SYS_LASTMODF_DTTM = sysdate
  WHERE USER.TABLE_NAME.ID = v_id AND
        USER.TABLE_NAME.CODE= v_code;

END IF;
COMMIT;
END updateTABLE;
```

Wondering how should I fix it? Did some search here but didn't find what I need.

Comment: You can check the values in the `WHERE` clause of the `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: `BEGIN
UPDATE USER.TABLE_NAME
        SET FIRSTNAME = v_firstname,
            LASTNAME = v_lastname,
            EMAIL = v_email,
            PHONE = v_phone,
            SYS_LASTMODF_DTTM = sysdate
  WHERE USER.TABLE_NAME.ID = v_id AND
        USER.TABLE_NAME.CODE= v_code AND
        (USER.TABLE_NAME.FIRSTNAME != v_firstname OR
        USER.TABLE_NAME.LASTNAME != v_lastname OR
        USER.TABLE_NAME.EMAIL != v_email OR
        USER.TABLE_NAME.PHONE != v_phone);

COMMIT;`

Comment: It works perfectly~ thanks a lot!

Comment: If you want to know more, search for cursors. You will see that your initial source does not makes sense.

Comment: And also, this code makes more sense on a trigger.

Comment: @JeanJung I searched for cursors. I know what you mean now. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was in the comment, I just want to put it here in case somebody need it later.

```
BEGIN 
  UPDATE USER.TABLE_NAME 
    SET FIRSTNAME = v_firstname, 
        LASTNAME = v_lastname, 
        EMAIL = v_email, 
        PHONE = v_phone, 
        SYS_LASTMODF_DTTM = sysdate 
    WHERE USER.TABLE_NAME.ID = v_id 
      AND USER.TABLE_NAME.CODE= v_code 
      AND (USER.TABLE_NAME.FIRSTNAME != v_firstname 
        OR USER.TABLE_NAME.LASTNAME != v_lastname 
        OR USER.TABLE_NAME.EMAIL != v_email 
        OR USER.TABLE_NAME.PHONE != v_phone); 
COMMIT;
```